# Updating Intel Centrino Wireless-N1030 wifi driver

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, intel-centrino

I have a dell laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. I have an Intel Wireless-N 1030 WiFi driver. The wifi works fine on Ubuntu, but it doesn't work at all on Windows. I think the driver may be corrupt or need an upgrade.

The driver was 15.0.4.11, but I installed Wireless_16.11.0_Ds64.exe from  https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23723 by downloading it on Ubuntu and running it on Windows. It still didn't work, so I installed http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/driverdetails?driverid=P7G35 using the same method.

It still doesn't work and I'm not sure if I have the right drivers or if I installed them correctly. How do I find the driver I need for it to work? Are there any other relevant specs I should be looking at?

Comment: You can try running Intel's [automatic driver identifier](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/wireless). However since your Wi-Fi connection won't work, you'd have to either use an Ethernet connection or use a mobile internet device to connect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an ethernet or mobile internet connection readily available.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try downloading [DriverIdentifier](http://driveridentifier.com/) from Ubuntu and run it on Windows. After collecting some hardware information, it'll automatically open up a web page in your default web browser. You'll need to copy this web page (use the address bar of the browser to find it) and open it from within Ubuntu. It'll take you to a page with latest driver updates for detected devices and you may download the correct driver from there.

Comment: What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the Wi-Fi card?

Comment: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008A&SUBSYS_53258086&REV_34
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008A&SUBSYS_53258086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008A&CC_028000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_008A&CC_0280

Comment: Try installing the drivers listed in this post: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19501856/20345357.aspx#20345357